# Find a class inside the parent of a clicked element

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I'm trying to find the class .post-info inside the parent of a clicked element, .toggle-info. Right now all the .post-info's on the page toggle. I'm trying to get only that one .post-info to toggle inside it's parent container, .post.

```
<div class="post">
 <div class="toggle-info">Toggle Btn</div>

 <div class="post-info">
  <p>Toggle this content</p>
 </div>

</div>


$(".toggle-info").click(function () {   
  $(".post-info").animate({ 
    height: "toggle",
    opacity:"toggle"
  }, 520, 'swing');
});
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$(this).closest(".post").find(".post-info").animate(...)
```

This goes up the parent chain from where the click happens and finds the `.post` class, then finds the `.post-info` in that parent and then applies the animation to that.  This is very flexible in that .post-info could be anywhere in the .post parent and this would work.  You can see it work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/AeYZU/

For this particular exact HTML, you could also use this:

```
$(this).next().animate(...)
```

This would get the next sibling after the div that was clicked on.  Note, that this method (as opposed to the previous one) relies on the exact position of `.post-info` as the next sibling and will break if its position changes.  You can see this one work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/qGCLx/